# Wrong result converting MsgPack timestamp 64 fields to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, msgpack

I am trying to implement the [MsgPack TimeStamp 64 type](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#timestamp-extension-type) in C#. This is what the specification says:

```
timestamp 64 stores the number of seconds and nanoseconds that have elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
in 32-bit unsigned integers:
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------|-+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  0xd7  |   -1   | nanosec. in 30-bit unsigned int |   seconds in 34-bit unsigned int    |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+------^-+--------+--------+--------+--------+

* Timestamp 64 format can represent a timestamp in [1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 UTC, 2514-05-30 01:53:04.000000000 UTC) range.
* In timestamp 64 and timestamp 96 formats, nanoseconds must not be larger than 999999999.
```

Note that the seconds field is thirty-**four** bits, not thirty-two. So the max value can be computed by shifting a 32-bit max value unsigned int left two bits and setting the now-cleared two least-significant bits.

I tried to verify this with the following C# code but got different results:

```cs
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); // the zero starting point
long maxSecs = ((long)uint.MaxValue << 2) | 3; // 17179869183
long maxNanoSec = 999999999; // not uint.MaxValue
TimeSpan maxNanoSecSpan = new TimeSpan(maxNanoSec * 100); // 1 tick = 100 nanosec.
DateTime MaxFExt8 = epoch.AddSeconds(maxSecs).Add(maxNanoSecSpan); 
Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("Timestamp 64 : ", epoch.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff"), " - ", MaxFExt8.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")));
```

The output is:

> Timestamp 64 : 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 - 2514-05-30 04:39:42.9999900

That is 2 hours, 46 minutes and 39 seconds too many...

After [opening an issue](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/298) about the difference, others checked and found they got the same results as the specs. One using the MacOS builtin NSDate type, the other using ruby.

I figure there must be a bug in my 6 lines of code, but I have been staring at it too long...

P.S. Note that this is not the MsgPack implementation yet, I first need to get the this right before I can start verifying my real code with unit tests. Conversion between little-endian and big-endian stuff with those shifted bits will only add more confusion if the basis is already broken....

Comment: Just an FYI, 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC can be written as `DateTime.UnixEpoch` (in .NET Core, .NET 5.0+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are multiplying nanoseconds when you should be dividing: `TimeSpan maxNanoSecSpan = new TimeSpan(maxNanoSec * 100);`.